# ListView along with http request inside the builder keeps on refreshing infinitely even though itemCount is constant

Tags: flutter

In the code snippet -

The http request keeps on running forever and the `ListView` keeps on updating as a result forever too.

1 -  To my understanding, shouldn't it run only 5 times as `itemCount` is given as 5?

2 -  What would be a better way to generate different http requests for different items of the list 
    without storing it in a list beforehand? (kind of like cached images)

```
////
        ListView.separated(
                  separatorBuilder: (context, int) => Divider(),
                  itemCount: 5,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                http.get('http://icanhazdadjoke.com',
                    headers: {'Accept': 'text/plain'}).then((value) async {
                  var s =value;

              setState(() {
                joke = s.body;
              });

            });

            return ListTile(
              title: Text(index.toString()),
              subtitle: Text(joke),
            );
          },
        ),
////
```

Comment: Have you tried to separate the api call and set itemcount as response list length?

Comment: Yes, but I wanted a cache kind of implementation for if I was to implement the same for 4k images for example.

Comment: Your setState call is causing problem. Its rebuilding your widget again and again and initiating get call. So it should be seperated outside build method.

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your api call and your view logic should separated. Http calls may take a while to load and your ListView expects to build initially and only change when the state changes. What you are trying to achieve will work with the following code:

```
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {

  List<String> jokes = [];

  @override
  initState(){
    loadJokes();
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Google Fonts'),
      ),
      body: ListView.separated(
        separatorBuilder: (context, int) => Divider(),
        itemCount: jokes.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(index.toString()),
            subtitle: Text(jokes[index]),
          );
        },

      )
    );
  }

  void loadJokes() async {
    for( var i = 0 ; i <= 5; i++ ) {
      http.get('http://icanhazdadjoke.com',
        headers: {'Accept': 'text/plain'}).then((value) async {
          setState(() {
            jokes.add(value.body.toString());
          });
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On first time, when widget builds, it triggers `get` call.

Every time the `get` call gets its response, `then` you are calling `setState`. Calling set state will rebuild the widget again. Which will result in triggering the `get` call again.

you can make `get` call only once by calling it from `initState`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MainPage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    ),
  );
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  Future<String> joke;

  @override
  void initState() {
    joke = _httpGetRequest();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<String> _httpGetRequest() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
      'http://icanhazdadjoke.com',
      headers: {'Accept': 'text/plain'},
    );
    return response.body;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Demo")),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: joke,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          else if (snapshot.hasError)
            return Center(
              child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
            );
          else
            return ListView.separated(
              separatorBuilder: (context, int) => Divider(),
              itemCount: 5,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(index.toString()),
                  subtitle: Text(snapshot.data ?? "null"),
                );
              },
            );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```